# Synchronizing subscribers to JMS Topic in active/active mode (WebLogic)

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, jms-topic

We work with WebLogic server, consuming JMS messages from a Topic. We have several nodes, working in active/active subscriber mode, without shared states other than dB (Oracle). The problem is, we have a requirement that only one of the subscribers (the first to receive the message) needs to perform the actual business logic upon receiving the message from the Topic.

What will be the best approach for synchronization between the subscribers? Is there some way to handle this on the WebLogic itself e.g. collect the messages from the Topic, posing as a single subscriber, and putting it in a queue - so that subscribers to WebLogic will listen to the Queue instead of the original Topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the concept of Shared subscription in JMS where messages for a topic are shared across multiple consumers. To share a subscriptions for a topic, all consumers must use same client id and subscription id (or key). More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13727/advpubsub.htm#JMSPG967).